# How was this comment that isn't 15 characters posted?

Tags: support, comments

How did this user get around the 15 character minimum for comments? This user isn't a mod, and only has around 1500 rep.

[image: Comment with the contents: "No."]

Comment: You shove in some unicode stuff.

Comment: Li‍‍‍ke t‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​hi‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍s

Comment: (by including zero-width spaces, unicode U+200B). You can figure that out by inspecting the element and trying to remove or copy characters, or iterating through the characters. They're before the _s_

Comment: Wow. Interesting.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Doesn't this mean that people can ignore the minimum of 15 completely?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Funny! Even my firefox doesn't show your U+200B-s.

Comment: @Xcoder It does, but you need to consciously bypass it, meaning that you know comments aren't intended for this. For questions and answers, the limit is even easier to bypass. An alternative trick is a boldfaced italicized dot ___.___, which takes 7 characters

Comment: For questions and answers there are `&#8203;`. For comments...  long code wrappers may suffice.

Comment: `````````````:P`````````````

Comment: (although, this is not related to [se], just Unicode, so it is not on-topic here)

Comment: @Xcoder you have to also consider that no matter what checks you put in (such as checking for zero space characters), someone will usually find a way to work around it, then it becomes as escalating battle.  So a decision has to be made as to whether such measures are needed.  And the developers obviously decided a simple deterrent was needed to make it harder to post short comments

Comment: **.** **.** **.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to disambiguate: *all* users are subject to the character limitations, save for Stack Overflow programmers who could insert something into the database to bypass integrity checks (although that probably won't happen).

Now, the reason that this works is because there are *certain* Unicode non-printing characters which can be stuffed into a comment box and still count towards the character limit.  Additionally, formatting characters (namely `*` and `_`) also count towards the character limit, so you could do some fancy work with emphasizing a piece of punctuation ***.***